# Expecting End of File Exception in parsing xml data for Blackberry application

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry, java-me

I am getting parser exception as "Expecting End of File" while parsing xml data for Blackberry application?

How do I fix it?

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful.

Comment: Im trying to parse a normal xml string that comes from server.I am using DocumentBuilderFactory's parse method to parse it. Few of my xml strings get parsed successfully with this,and few of them give the above exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: what size of those failed xml string? is it well formed? I would advice to implement some logging there, to know exactly what xml string failed to parse.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the the same org.xml.sax.SAXException while developing a child class of org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler for processing an XML file on Blackberry.

The issue in my case was that my sample XML file was not well-formed. Specifically, there was not only one root element in the XML file. My broken XML file had several root-level tags, and SAX was complaining that it found a second one. The file looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<number>one</number>
<number>two</number>
<number>three</number>
```

To fix it, I just encapsulated those items into one root element named "counting":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<counting>
<number>one</number>
<number>two</number>
<number>three</number>
</counting>
```

You can see a few of the XML rules [on Wikipedia here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml#Well-formedness_and_error-handling)

Comment: I hit exactly this problem, thanks for your very useful solution!