# XQUERY error : Query: <>, line 1, column 7: [XPST0003] syntax error, unexpected "'QName'", expecting end of file

Tags: xquery

I'm completely new to `Xquery`. Theres a code I have to run. I received the below error while doing so:

> Query: <>, line 1, column 7: [XPST0003] syntax error, unexpected "'QName'", expecting end of file.

Can someone please elaborate on this type of error? I searched many forums but couldn't find a concrete solution.

Comment: Please share the code you are running and some information about your environment. If we can recreate the error, we might be able to help.

Comment: This type of error is called a syntax error.  It happens when the person who creates the query makes a certain kind of mistake.  Just as with syntax errors in other computer languages, syntax errors in XQuery can be corrected only by (a) random changes and a lot of luck, or (b) someone who knows the language in question and can see the text containing the syntax error.  If you want Stack Overflow readers to help you find the syntax error and explain the error message you are getting, you *must* show a small (!) example illustrating your problem and describe your environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expecting End of File Exception in parsing xml data for Blackberry application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755569/expecting-end-of-file-exception-in-parsing-xml-data-for-blackberry-application)